# Arrangement of textviews

Tags: android

How to place textview one below the other in android layout xml.
For example i need something like below:

textview 1 : textview 5
textview 2 : textview 6
textview 3 : textview 7
textview 4 : textview 8
.....          .....

note :Textview 1,2,3,4 one below other and parallel textview 5,,6,7,8 on below other  vertically

which layout is best to implementation for the above example and how to implement it like should i need  to take textview 1 and textview 5 in single relative layout will that work for rest textviews ??
I need all textview after ":" be be aligned properly in space and before ":" also same

Comment: use LinearLayout virtically and horizontally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this but the simplest method is this:

Declare a LinearLayout and set the orientation to `horizontal`. Inside that LinearLayout, declare two other linear layouts whose orientations are both `vertical`. Adjust the width and height to your taste. A representation is shown below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--TextViews in the first row (top to bottom)-->

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--Textviews in the second row (top to bottom)-->

    </LinearLayout>
```

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!

Comment: thanks...it helped and this is what i was looking for.